# Copy paste option not appearing for EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have created a `Activity` which extends `FixedExpandableListActivity`.
In my Activity, I am having `EditText` where in after entering some text, and doing a long press on the `EditText`, copy paste option is not appearing.
Doing multiple taps on the `EditText`, copy paste option pops up and disappear.

Issue is observed on 4.1.2.

Can some one please help out how to fix this issue.

Comment: Show us the XML code where you declared the EditText

Comment: Seeing similar behavior on 4.4.2, programmatic `EditText`. Maybeit's related to running in an activity without an action bar.

Answer (score 0):

My gremlin for this problem was a combination of `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and a `View.OnLayoutChangeListener` which was reparenting the `EditText`, for unrelated reasons. (Removing the `EditText` caused the copy/paste actions to disappear, sensibly enough.) Hard to track down.